# swap records in dataframe columns based on anothers column value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data-frame as below :

```
A     B    C
315  105  ABC
315  135  ABC
105  44   ABC
105  70   ABC
105  72   ABC
105  315  XYZ
105  319  XYZ
```

If the value is XYZ in column C, i need to swap values in Col A & B, otherwise let it be as is.

What is the most effective way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Find out rows that `C == XYZ`:

```
idx = df.C == 'XYZ'
```

Then use `loc` to locate the values in column `A` and `B`, swap the values and assign them back; Notice the `values` to convert the result from a data frame to a numpy array so that the assignment will not try to align the column index (which will result in no effect):

```
df.loc[idx, ['A', 'B']] = df.loc[idx, ['B', 'A']].values

df
#     A   B   C
#0  315 105 ABC
#1  315 135 ABC
#2  105 44  ABC
#3  105 70  ABC
#4  105 72  ABC
#5  315 105 XYZ
#6  319 105 XYZ
```

Comment: perfect solution !!
Thanks

Comment: One more help please @Psidom , Now i have duplicates in data.
We identify duplicates as a set of Column A & B values combined.
So, in above example, the only duplicates are row #0 & #5.

How do we eliminate duplicates from the above result ?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['A','B'])` if you want to keep one of the duplicated; `df.drop_duplicates(['A','B'], keep=False)` if you want to remove both of them.

Comment: The above will remove duplicates from each columns seperately.
the problem is how do i find duplicates for combination of Column A&B and then remove duplicates ?

Comment: This removes duplicates for combination of A&B actually. If you check the outputs twice, rows `2,3,4` are kept untouched even though `A` is duplicated.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help :) 
I did try this, but its not working out somehow. I see 7 records still.
Can you try running this (if you havent) ? Or help me figure out why they werent deleted ?

Comment: I did try running this. It gave back six rows for the first case and five rows for the second; It's possible you have float data type of column A and B, if they are calculated from different sources; Then you could have the float number inaccuracy(if you are not aware of this, try `0.7 - 0.6 == 0.1`) which means they look the same but actually not equal.

Comment: Also my python version is `3.5.1`, pandas version `0.19.2`; And it seems work fine for me on the given example.

Comment: I think that MAYBE the issue. I use python 2.7 & pandas 0.19.0
Also,The columns A & B are as-is as shown in example, not float.

Comment: Not sure then, just tested in python `2.7.13` and pandas `0.19.2`; Works as well, might restart your python session.